# XCode iOS - home screen style navigation

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios4, interface-builder

Sorry this is a pretty silly question, but I cannot think what the actual menu style is called. I'm trying to find a tutorial on how to create a instructions page that you flick through left and right to see more instructions. Basically exactly how the home screen works with dots representing how many screens there are and which screen the user is on, plus the same animation where if you flick left/right the next one slides on.

If anyone knows what these are commonly referred to as I can go look up some tutorials.

Thanks a lot,

Chris

Comment: I've read it twice, but your question is still not clear, can you please elaborate it more?

Comment: Sorry! Take Apple's 'Reminders' app for example, you can flick between completed and uncompleted lists, and down the bottom you see two little dots, one is illuminated to show it's the active screen. http://wpuploads.appadvice.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Reminders.png

So basically the functionality I'm after is having a gallery like component that can be browsed through, while the rest of the view remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This control is called a [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And here's a link to a [tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/).

Answer (score 3):

Use a UIScrollview with pagingEnabled. 
add a UIPageControl to the view (wherever you want to see the dots). 
Instruction pages should be added as subviews to the UIScrollView
Make sure to use UIScrollView and UIPageControl delegates to update the page in the pageControl.

If you need more info on how to implement this, search with keywords UIScrollView and UIPageControl